# .net core call oracle function put returned value in first parameter

Tags: oracle, .net-core

.net core 3.1
nuget: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core 2.19.91

Oracle function:

```
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE FUNCTION        GET_TOTAL_SALES 
(
    PARAM1 IN VARCHAR2,
    PARAM2 IN VARCHAR2 
)
    RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
BEGIN
    RETURN 'abc';
END GET_TOTAL_SALES;
```

.net core code:

```
var cmdText = "GET_TOTAL_SALES";
using (var connection = new OracleConnection(connStr))
{
    using (var command = new OracleCommand(cmdText, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        var param1 = new OracleParameter("PARAM1", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
        param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param1.Value = "param1Value";
        command.Parameters.Add(param1);

        var param2 = new OracleParameter("PARAM2", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
        param2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param2.Value = "param2Value";
        command.Parameters.Add(param2);

        var returnValue = new OracleParameter("returnValue", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
        returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        command.Parameters.Add(returnValue);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Console.WriteLine(returnValue.Value); //""
        Console.WriteLine(param1.Value); //"abc"
    }
}
```

The result is that the returned value is putted into the first parameter (param1) and not into the returnValue. Why? Help!

Comment: It seems that you are using the EDITION feature of Oracle (`NONEDITIONABLE FUNCTION`). Are you sure you are calling the right VERSION of your function ?

Answer (score 2):

I asked Oracle and got a reply:
"This is expected behavior. The first parameter bound for a function must be the return value. From the doc:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-data-access-components/19.3.2/odpnt/featOraCommand.html

I know, it is crazy.
We can also use binding by name:

```
command.BindByName = true;
```

and then order doesn't matter.